# Get return from method AuthorizeCore

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to use claims authorization and i'm using this data-annotation

```
[ClaimsAuthorize(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")]
public void Test()
{
  ....
}
```

When i try to access *test* method i'm redirect to *AuthorizeCore* method:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
      var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity;
      var claim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimType);
      if(claim != null)
      {
          return claim.Value == ClaimValue;
      }
          return false;
 }
```

When my user is able to access *test* method these work fine but when user is not able to it nothing happens.

My question is: How can i get method return when it returns false?
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know `ClaimsAuthorise` is not part of .Net framework. Where did you get it? And what should happen when user does not have the right claim to access the action/controller?

Comment: This is how I've done this attribute: https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/Infrastructure/Identity/ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute.cs

Comment: @tailmax i create a class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute class, then i override Authorizecore from there. Currently my code doesn't do anithung and i need to show some message saying the user have no access to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @trailmax i can solve my problem:

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }

    public ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute(string claimType, string claimValue)
    {
        ClaimType = claimType;
        ClaimValue = claimValue;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimType);

        if (claim != null && claim.Value == ClaimValue)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(){
                {"controller", "Contas"},
                {"action", "NaoAutorizado"}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot